# When to call AsyncTask in Fragments in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

I have a ViewPager of fragments.
For each fragments, in the onCreateView(), I use AsyncTask to query the server.
I create the fragments in FragmentPagerAdapter's getItem().
However, because getItem() method will be called for the visible fragment and also the adjacent fragments, I am calling the onCreateView() and thus the AsyncTask of the adjacent Fragment even though the fragment is not visible.
How do I only call the AsyncTask of the visible fragment?

Is using onPageSelected() for the ViewPager the correct solution?
I used this method to call AsyncTask instead of in onCreateView() but then the onCreateView() of the fragment is not called.

Thank you.

Comment: why -1 for this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the method of Fragment:

```
setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
     super.setUserVisibleHint( isVisibleToUser);
     if(isVisiableToUser) {
     }
}
```